# ASP.net application wont start when selecting "Multiple startup projects:" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio

I have just created 2 new projects:

- Frontend, an angular application
- Backend, an ASP.net application

When run by them self they work as expected but when i chose "Multiple startup projects:" only Frontend starts.

Any idea on why this is?

**Build observations:**
[image]

**Startup configuration**

[image: Multiple startup projects, configuration]

**Frontend, proxy.conf.js:**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:5001",
    secure: false
  }
]
```

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

**Backend, launchSettings.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15774",
      "sslPort": 44322
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Backend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```